# How to use Query String parameters in the ASP.NET MVC API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

```
[RoutePrefix("web/api")]
public class UsersController : BaseController
{
    [Route("users")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Response<List<UserDTO>> Get(string q, string ex)
```

I am trying to make the get function respond to : 
web/api/users?q=sd&ex=1

But it is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[RoutePrefix("web/api")]
public class UsersController : BaseController
{
    [Route("users")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Response<List<UserDTO>> Get(string q, string ex)
```

Sorry to bother you all, but this works perfectly fine. What I was doing wrong is that I had some controllers in the MVC project which pointed to the same url. As a result I was getting 404.

But thanks a lot all.

Answer (score 1):

I gess your mistake is that you using `RoutePrefix` on controller class with `Route` on method.

If you want to call url like you show you should define your controller like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("web/api/users")]
public class UsersController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public Response<List<UserDTO>> Get(string q, string ex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
`[RoutePrefix("web/api")]
public class UsersController : BaseController
{
    [Route("users/{q}/{ex}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Response<List<UserDTO>> Get(string q, string ex)`
```

and just call api like : `web/api/users/text1/text2`

Comment: it won't work with url like `web/api/users?q=sd&ex=1`

Comment: call api like : web/api/users/text1/text2

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom routes

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "NameOfRoute",
    routeTemplate: "web/{controller}/{action}?q={q}&ex={ex}",
    defaults: new { controller = "controller-name", action = "action-name", 
        q = RouteParameter.Optional, ex= RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: I want to use Attribute Routing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order to be able to have multiple `GET` methods in the same controller, you must add your custom routes:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Then, in your controlller you need to mark the parameter as `FromUri` in order to tell the method to expect the parameter from the URI. This way, you will be able to call the method the following way:

```
/web/api/users/Get?q="your string1"&ex="ex"

public Response<List<UserDTO>> Get([FromUri]string q, [FromUri]string ex)
```

If this is the only `GET` method, you may skip the part with mapping custom routes.

Hope this helps.

Best of luck!

Comment: I want to use attribute routing/